# Search multiple columns for multiple values - SAS

Tags: sas

I am trying to search multiple columns for multiple values and a resulting/new column that shows the count of multiple values.
For example, I want to look in columns TDIAG1-TDIAG10 for values T3100-T3199 and if any of these columns have the values create a new column "Count" which shows the count of how many values are listed in each record.

Can someone please help.

Output example
[image]

Sample data

```
data temp;
informat ID TDIAG1-TDIAG10 $5.;
input ID TDIAG1-TDIAG10;
datalines;
1 T250 T3100 X32 Y929 U739 Z509 N481 U822 U862 B951
2 T2201 T3100 X09 Y929 U739 B9688 B956 B951 Z0651 E1151
3 T3100 X19 Y929 U739 Z720 T3120 D649 E1122 E1151 B951
4 T3100 X32 Y929 U739 R55 Y9204 U739 E1069 L984 B9688
5 T3100 T793 X18 Y929 U7303 E1169 Y9209 U732 E119 B951
6 T3100 X19 Y9201 U739 B956 B951 Z0651 U739 Z509 Y929
7 T3100 X08 Y9209 U739  T3122 I500 T3160 Y9209 U732 E119
8 T3100 X09 Y929 U739 E119 Z9222 U739 Z720 T3120 B951
9 T3100 T2122 T2222 T2221 T232 T242 T261 T272 T3160 Y9209
;
run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking for T31xx, then it's relatively easy using arrays...

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  array diag{*} TDIAG: ; /* all the TDIAGxx columns */
  Count = 0 ;
  do i = 1 to dim(diag) ;
    Count + (diag{i} =: 'T31' and length(diag{i}) = 5) ;
  end ;
  drop i ;
run ;
```